# Can I (DNS) map one subdomain to multiple Play Framework entry points

Tags: web-services, networking, playframework, dns

Is the scenario below possible? A warning that I understand DNS only in its basic form.

We have an API (built using [Play](https://typesafe.com/)) that we would like to make available via a an address say http://api.publicname.com

However, we would like to split this API in 2 Play projects (e.g. myapione and myapitwo).
Then access them using only 1 domain but two separate "subfolders"

So I have been looking for the possibility of mapping say...

http://myinternal.domain:9000 to http://api.publicname.com/myapione

... and another [Play](https://typesafe.com/) application

http://myinternal.domain:9001 to http://api.publicname.com/myapitwo

The end result we are looking for is something like below. 
We would have calls looking like...

http://myinternal.domain:9000/products/123 is also http://api.publicname.com/myapione/products/123

http://myinternal.domain:9001/orders/456 is also http://api.publicname.com/myapitwo/orders/456

Comment: I don't think so, but you can always put some proxy (Apache/nginx) in front of both play apps and do the right redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective:

```
Public URL              -> maps to -> internal URL
http://api.publicname.com/myapione -> http://localhost:9000
http://api.publicname.com/myapitwo -> http://localhost:9001
```

is achieved, as @applicius said, by a "front-facing" or "origin" HTTP server which proxies the request through to the lower level "application" or "service" HTTP servers. It isn't really about virtual hosts though.

Nginx, Apache, etc are common. I think nginx is great. A commercial product which does this and is amazing is Zeus or ZXTM. It was bought out I think so I'm not sure if it's still available on its own.

Configuration for nginx for the above, something like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  api.publicname.com/myapione;

    location /myapione {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }

    location /myapitwo {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:9001;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

This approach lets you "stitch" together as many services as you like and appear as one to external callers. For example, to serve static file assets under `static` and a front-facing HTML server for everything not matched under `/`:

```
    location /static/ {
        alias /app/myapp-pages/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
```

With that in place:

```
Public URL              -> maps to -> internal URL
http://api.publicname.com/myapione -> http://localhost:9000
http://api.publicname.com/myapitwo -> http://localhost:9001
http://api.publicname.com/static   -> local file assets
http://api.publicname.com/...      -> http://localhost:8000
```

This doesn't do any load balancing, but you could put the other services on some host:port that does the load balancing, and then point nginx at it.

The `ZXTM` product is interesting because it does both the above proxying and load balancing. (I'm not endorsing it more than anything else, it's just that I have seen it used in production and it's impressive.)

Side note that Play, while excellent, is better suited to rendering pages and providing a higher level API that combines calls to lower HTTP services. Lower-level HTTP services can be written with a toolkit like DropWizard, which focuses only on providing an API not pages.

Answer (score 1):

Play doesn't manage virtualhost concept. If required, you have to do it with an HTTP frontend server: Apache, Nginx, Varnish

For example in Nginx:

```
server {
  listen: 80
  server_name main.virtual.host alias.virtual.host;

  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```