# Restrict access to specific IP in Play Framework (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

How can I restrict access to list of IP in Play Framework using Scala?

I'm using Play Framework 2.2.4

I found solution for Java:
 http://feadro.com/simple-ip-access-list-for-play-2-1-with-java/

How should I do it in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stick the IPs you want to restrict to in the `application.conf`.

```
myapp.ipwhitelist = ["192.168.1.1", ...]
```

Then make a [global filter](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/ScalaHttpFilters) which is applied to every incoming request, something like:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.mvc._

object IPFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextFilter: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
      // read the IPs as a Scala Seq (converting from the Java list)
      val ips: Seq[String] = current.configuration.getStringList("myapp.ipwhitelist")
            .map(_.asScala).getOrElse(Seq.empty)

      // Check we've got an allowed IP, otherwise ignore the
      // request body and immediately return a forbidden.
      if (ips.contains(requestHeader.remoteAddress)) nextFilter(requestHeader)
      else Iteratee.ignore[Array[Byte]]
        .map(_ => Results.Forbidden(s"Bad IP! ${requestHeader.remoteAddress}"))
    }
  }
}
```

Then enable that in your application Global object:

```
object Global extends WithFilters(IPFilter) with GlobalSettings
```

If you want more flexibility you can use the same logic but with [Action composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition) instead of a global filter.

Comment: Might be an idea to read the IPs into a `lazy val` just once at startup, unless you _really_ need the whitelist to be re-read from file on every request.

Comment: This wouldn't work if you have `play.filters.hosts` enabled, would it?

Comment: In play 2.6 I used `Accumulator.done(Results.Forbidden)` instead of Iteratee

Answer (score 0):

I think that for production HTTP environment requiring more than simple configuration (public, accepting any HTTP request), an HTTP frontend service should be used to dispatch appropriately request to Play.

As for [Can I (DNS) map one subdomain to multiple Play Framework entry points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211452/can-i-dns-map-one-subdomain-to-multiple-play-framework-entry-points/25212090#25212090) , there is advantage of using a service such Apache, Nginx or Varnish to configure HTTP ACL (Access Control List). For example in Varnish:

```
acl my-acl {
    "an-authorized-host";
    "1.2.3.4";
}

# Then ...
if (!client.ip ~ my-acl) {
    error 405 "Not allowed.";
}
```